# Prove that the limits are unbounded

Tags: calculus

> Let $R(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials and $\deg(P) > \deg(Q)$. Using the definition of limit, prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} R(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} R(x)$ have no limits.

We must show that either $R(x)$ increases or decreases without bound, but I find it hard to utilize the definition of the limit if we don't know which one. Should I break this up into cases where they increase and decrease without bound?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Euclidean division.

I.e., that since $\deg P > \deg Q$, there are polynomials $A, B$, such that $P = AQ + B$, with $0 \le \deg B < \deg Q$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dotsb+a_nx^n+\dotsb+a_mx^m$ and $Q(x)=b_0+b_1x+\dotsb+b_nx^n$ where $m>n$ where the leading coefficents are nonzero.

Then $$\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{a_0+a_1x+\dotsb+a_nx^n+\dotsb+a_mx^m}{b_0+b_1x+\dotsb+b_nx^n}$$

Factor our $x^n$ from the numerator and denominator and conclude the result.

Comment: How is that using the definition of the limit?